# How to dynamically add an AttributeSet to a TextView?

Tags: java, android

I would like to add `textView`s to a table when a button is clicked. So here is what I am doing inside the OnClickListener:

```
todoTable.addView(new TextView(this));
```

I would also like to add properties, like the text content or the background, to this dynamically created `TextView`. How would I do that then? Android Studio says to have a constructor like so

```
new TextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
```

What can I include in the AttributeSet parameter to give the TextView a value, for instance "Hello World!"?

Comment: Why can't someone answer the question right?  Android has a function that has two params one being AttributeSet.  What can be included in Attribute Set?

Comment: @JPM because that constructor is intended to be called by the Android OS only, it will put its own implementation of `AttributeSet` there, whose implementation class is actually a private class `XmlBlock.Parser`. so the only way to pass something there yourself is if you inflated that object from XML using framework methods.

Answer (score 9):

Do something like this, create a method that returns TextView and you can set your text too.  An easier way is to create a Text View layout only and just reuse that instead.  The AttributeSet is used primarily for when your creating a custom view and need to add more Attributes.

```
public TextView createTextView(String text) {
    String attributes =
            "<attribute xmlns:android=\"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android\" " +
            "android:layout_width=\"match_parent\" android:layout_height=\"wrap_content\" android:padding=\"10dp\" " +
            "android:background=\"@drawable/list_selector_background\" android:clickable=\"true\" " +
            "android:textAppearance = \"@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium\" android:textColor = \"@color/text_colors\" " +
            "android:text=\"" + text +  "\" android:gravity = \"left\" " + "\"/>";

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = null;
    try {
        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        parser.setInput(new StringReader(attributes));
        parser.next();
        AttributeSet attrs = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
        return new TextView(this, attrs);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new TextView(this);
}
```

Comment: Finally, a decent answer! Do you mind explaining what the `XMLPullParserFactory` is and what you did in the `try` and `catch`es?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. It crashes with `ClassCastException: android.util.XmlPullAttributes cannot be cast to android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser` error. Any ideas to solve this?